# Create a temporary, readonly buffer for test output

Tags: neovim

I want to create a Neovim plugin that automatically runs a test suite whenever a file is saved. Here's an overview:

1. If I save a Rust file, run `cargo test`
2. If there's not a buffer opened for the test output, automatically create the buffer
3. Mark that buffer as readonly
4. If I save another file, reuse the existing buffer
5. If the buffer is quit (e.g., `:q`), create a new buffer on the next test run

However, I'm currently facing three issues:

1. I cannot detect if when I quit the buffer
2. When the test output is longer than the buffer height, the buffer will not scroll down
3. When I want to quit Neovim, it asks me to save all these temporary buffers (which I don't want to do)

How can I resolve these issues? For reference, here's my code:

```lua
local buffer_number = -1

local function log(_, data)
    if data then
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer_number, -1, -1, true, data)
    end
end

local function open_buffer()
    if buffer_number == -1 then
        vim.api.nvim_command('botright vnew')
        buffer_number = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    end
end

local function autotest(pattern, command)
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
        group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("autotest", { clear = true }),
        pattern = pattern,
        callback = function()
            open_buffer()
            vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer_number, 0, -1, true, {})
            vim.fn.jobstart(command, {
                stdout_buffered = true,
                on_stdout = log,
                on_stderr = log,
            })
        end
    })
end

autotest("*.rs", { "cargo", "test" })
```

*P.S. I know there are several existing plugins for testing. I'm creating my own because I want to learn how to write neovim plugins.*

Comment: "If the buffer is quit (e.g., `:q`)," then "When I want to quit Neovim, it asks me to save all these temporary buffers (which I don't want to do)" => use `:q!` instead of `:q` for each buffer, and `:qa!` for all buffers. However, as it asks you to save, that means the buffers have been modified (there must be something you are doing wrong?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave it my best shot. I believe this addresses your questions and does what you're aiming to do.

```lua
local buffer_number = -1

local function log(_, data)
    if data then
        -- Make it temporarily writable so we don't have warnings.
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(buffer_number, "readonly", false)
        
        -- Append the data.
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer_number, -1, -1, true, data)

        -- Make readonly again.
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(buffer_number, "readonly", true)

        -- Mark as not modified, otherwise you'll get an error when
        -- attempting to exit vim.
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(buffer_number, "modified", false)

        -- Get the window the buffer is in and set the cursor position to the bottom.
        local buffer_window = vim.api.nvim_call_function("bufwinid", { buffer_number })
        local buffer_line_count = vim.api.nvim_buf_line_count(buffer_number)
        vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor(buffer_window, { buffer_line_count, 0 })
    end
end

local function open_buffer()
    -- Get a boolean that tells us if the buffer number is visible anymore.
    --
    -- :help bufwinnr
    local buffer_visible = vim.api.nvim_call_function("bufwinnr", { buffer_number }) ~= -1

    if buffer_number == -1 or not buffer_visible then
        -- Create a new buffer with the name "AUTOTEST_OUTPUT".
        -- Same name will reuse the current buffer.
        vim.api.nvim_command("botright vsplit AUTOTEST_OUTPUT")
        
        -- Collect the buffer's number.
        buffer_number = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
        
        -- Mark the buffer as readonly.
        vim.opt_local.readonly = true
    end
end

function autotest(pattern, command)
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
        pattern = pattern,
        callback = function()
            -- Open our buffer, if we need to.
            open_buffer()
        
            -- Clear the buffer's contents incase it has been used.
            vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer_number, 0, -1, true, {})

            -- Run the command.
            vim.fn.jobstart(command, {
                stdout_buffered = true,
                on_stdout = log,
                on_stderr = log,
            })
        end
    })
end

autotest("*.rs", { "cargo", "test" })
```

I added some comments to help explain each step but specifically for each of your problems:

1. **I cannot detect if when I quit the buffer**

Since you already have the buffer number, you can query to see if it's still visible. Just by using the same name when creating the new buffer we an reuse any existing ones.

2. **When the test output is longer than the buffer height, the buffer will not scroll down**

This was tricky, and I'm not sure if it's the best way, but I was able to query how many lines the buffer had and set the cursor of the buffer's window to the bottom.

3. **When I want to quit Neovim, it asks me to save all these temporary buffers (which I don't want to do)**

This is because the buffers are modified. Neovim by default doesn't want to make it easy to accidentally lose your work if you have active modifications. To get around that we can easily mark that it isn't modified!

Hope that helps.